# How does @Autowired work with parameterized types that are not initialized?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

The example I am looking at is KafkaTemplate.

The KafkaTemplate is Autowired as KafkaTemplate.
The configuration I am using has a ProducerFactory created.
Both constructors of KafkaTemplate require the use of this kind of factory.

I want to guess that any new instance of a class autowired is using Class.isAssignableFrom(Class) to find an appropriate dependency for creating the parameterized instance.

Note: The original reason this spawned investigation is the change in behavior between autowiring in KafkfaTemplate and KafkaTemplate(No types).

Is this assumption correct?
If so, what is the best way to design similar configuration?
Is there a reason to use Kafka's implementation over using the interface 'FactoryBean'?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that [Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) has required property, you can use to mark bean as required

> **required**
>   Declares whether the annotated dependency is required.

```
@Autowired(required=true)
KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate
```